# Excel VBA to search a website's search box and click a link/button

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel VBA to log into a website, then type a .txt file name in a search box and click a button/link to search for it in the resulting second page. The resulting third page has an icon you have to click to download the file. Lastly I want to input the info in the .txt file to a new excel spreadsheet.

My getLogin function works and I successfully log into the website. Stepping through with F8 I can see each line of code entering in my username and password values in the respective fields. I'm on the second page level where I want to search in a searchbox using a filename, but at

```
If Not FileN Is Nothing And FileN.Length > 0 Then
        FileN(0).Value = fileName
```

in the SearchFile function, when I step through it using F8, I see it keeps skipping FileN(0).Value = fileName and doesn't input the file name. The same happens for the link I click to search,

```
Set ElementCol = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each l In ElementCol
        If l.href = "javascript:myFunction('/mailbox/jsp/MBIList.jsp')" Then
            l.Click
```

It doesn't enter the If Statement and therefore doesn't click it.

My code so far:

```
Sub getComponents()

   Dim WebAddressIn As String
   Dim ie As Object

   WebAddressIn = "https://..."

   'get ie instance to work with that is logged in
   Set ie = getLogin(WebAddressIn, "usern", "pw")

    Do Until ie.readyState = 4
    Loop

     ie.Visible = True

     Dim fileName As String
     fileName = Format(Now(), "yyyyMMdd") & ".TXT"
     Set ie = searchFile(fileName, ie)

End Sub

Function searchFile(fileName As String, ie As Object)
Dim Doc As Object, lastRow As Long, tblTR As Object
    Dim UserString As String
    Dim FileN As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim ElementCol As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim AllText As String

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    Set FileN = ie.document.getElementsByName("MsgNamePattern")
    If Not FileN Is Nothing And FileN.Length > 0 Then
        FileN(0).Value = fileName
    End If

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    Set ElementCol = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each l In ElementCol
        If l.href = "javascript:myFunction('/mailbox/jsp/MBIList.jsp')" Then
            l.Click
    Exit For
        End If
    Next l

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    Set searchFile = ie
    Set ie = Nothing

End Function

Function getLogin(WebAddressIn As String, UserNameIn As String, PasswordIn As String)
Dim Doc As Object, lastRow As Long, tblTR As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = False
    Dim UserString As String
    Dim PWString As String
    ie.Navigate2 WebAddressIn
    ie.Visible = True

    Dim UserN As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim PW As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim ElementCol As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim AllText As String

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    ' enter username and password in textboxes
    Set UserN = ie.document.getElementsByName("userid")
    If Not UserN Is Nothing And UserN.Length > 0 Then
        ' fill in first element named "username", assumed to be the login name field
        UserN(0).Value = UserNameIn
    End If

    Set PW = ie.document.getElementsByName("password")
    ' password
    If Not PW Is Nothing And PW.Length > 0 Then
        ' fill in first element named "password", assumed to be the password field
        PW(0).Value = PasswordIn
    End If

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

    'Clicks the Sign in button
    Set ElementCol = ie.document.getElementsByName("submit")
    For Each btnInput In ElementCol
        If btnInput.Value = "*Sign In" Then
            btnInput.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next btnInput

    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop

     Set getLogin = ie
    Set ie = Nothing

End Function
```

And here's the relevant HTML code on this second resulting page:

The Search Box -

```
<input type="text" name="MsgNamePattern" size="20" onblur="validateMessageName(this)">
```

The link to search -

```
<td align="center" valign="center"> <a href="javascript:myFunction('/mailbox/jsp/List.jsp')" onmouseover="chgButton('Go','GoOver'); window.status=''; return true;" onmouseout="chgButton('Go','GoOff'); window.status=''; return true;" onmousedown="chgButton('Go','GoDown'); return true;"><img border="0" src="/mailbox/images/go_off.gif" vspace="7" name="Go" align="top"></a> 
                  </td>
```